# How to query details of images in gallery that is attached to a post

Tags: customization, theme-development, themes, attachments, template-tags

I have several images attached to each post. I need to generate a gallery, but because it's heavily customized I don't want to use a gallery plugin, nor the gallery short code. It's also situated in a DIV that is totally separated from the post content/title etc. so it has to be stand-alone code in PHP, hard-coded.

Basically if there's a method to retrieve the list of attachments in a URL format.. and then pull in the proper sizes (filename_80X80.jpg or something along those lines - I know the filenames are manipulated after the thumbnail size).

I already have the thumbnail sizes covered using

```
add_image_size( 'ourwork_full', 589, 315, true );
add_image_size( 'ourwork_thumb', 80, 80, true );
```

in the funtions.php file of the template.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to use custom WP query? Or is there a function/template tag that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query for image attachments would be something like this (taken from [Get The Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/) plugin/extension) with [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children):

```
$attachments = get_children( array( 
    'post_parent' => $args['post_id'], 
    'post_status' => 'inherit', 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID' 
) );
```

Then you can loop through array and retrieve URLs with [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) which will get you URL and dimensions.

Comment: Managed to take this and create a custom function just for me.. thanks again, fantastic stuff.